# Dual passive low-pass filter

Tags: passive-networks, low-pass, class-d

I am building a class D amplifier and need to design passive low-pass filters for H-bridge with cut off frequencies at about 400 Hz. However, I am unsure about few things, this is the simplified equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f68r4I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Speaker values were measured using an RLC meter set to 100 Hz.

Lets say that the signal is coming into the L1 coil. Should I calculate the cut-off frequency only for L1, C1 pair? If L2 is grounded, do L2 and C2 have a noticeable effect on L1, C1 filter? How can I calculate it then?

I often see a capacitor in parallel with speaker what exactly is its purpose? I am thinking it is to lower reactive power of the speaker, right? To what \$cos\phi\$ should I lower it, and should I use middle range values for voltage and current?

Comment: The parallel capacitor does the same as C1 and C2

Comment: @Andyaka To create a higher order filter?

Comment: No it doesn't make a higher order filter - it's still a 2nd order filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the speaker coil had a centre tap. If you measured the voltage at the centre-tap relative to 0V it would be 0V with a balanced drive. Therefore you can split the problem in half and  imagine a grounded speaker with an impedance of 3.3 ohms and self inductance of 3.86mH.

Instead of C1 and C2 where they are, imagine just C1 connected across the half-speaker I have just described. Now proceed to calculate L1.

One word of warning - the 7.72mH self inductance of the speaker seems too high for my liking - I'm thinking that your RLC bridge has told you the effective parallel impedance (or maybe you meant 7.72uH)

Comment: Thanks, this clears up a lot! So the purpose of parallel capacitor (C3) is to increase the capacitance of the half filter, to allow for lower inductance values? How can I be sure what RLC meter showed (there is a setting for parallel/series measurement)? Even if the meter showed this as parallel impedence I get 600uH if I calculate it like this: $$Z=\sqrt{ESR^2-\frac{1}{\omega^2 L^2}}=7.72m$$
$$L=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega^2(ESR^2-Z^2)}}\approx 600uH$$